# Run system command after alert closed

Tags: notifications, applescript, apple-push-notifications, alert

How do I run a system command when an alert notification is closed?

[image: Time's up!]

I am triggering the above alert like this:

```
display notification "Timer for 0:00:00 finished" with title "Time's up!"
```

How do I do something when the <kbd>Close</kbd> button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure AppleScript you can't because the single threaded AppleScript is not able to handle the callbacks.

Comment: Using two separate applescripts? Or is there any system-wide event that is fired by its closing?

Comment: In Cocoa (Objective-C, Swift) there is a delegate method, in AppleScript there is none.

Comment: I ended up switching to an alert instead, which (as the applescript was called from python) worked out great because it seemed to be blocking on the main thread until closed.